# Can't find the area of a polar region

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, area

I've ran into a bit of a stopper on this one problem. I solved this other problem like this yesterday but this one seems to cancel itself out to zero. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with this problem.

**the original equation is:** r^2 = 81 cos(2x)

---

*this is what I've done to solve it so far*

[My work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VAan.jpg)

and I know that the graph looks like this

[My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UzVC.jpg)

---

The inetgral keeps canceling out to be zero and I'm not sure what to do with this andy more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is zero, because you are summing over a whole period of $\cos 2\theta$.

I suggest you calculate the area of one petal and multiply it by $8$. That is,
$$ 8 \cdot \frac{81}{2}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \cos 2\theta\,d\theta
$$
The reason to do so is sometimes the radius is negative, but the graph still encloses positive area.

Edit: The graph only has two petals, so the above needs to be changed.

Comment: that gave me 324. which from what i can gather the right answer is 81. so i don't know how to get that.

Comment: @RyanHenry Your graph is wrong, it only has $4$ petals.

Comment: ah that makes sense now that i look at it it should have only been 2 petals actually. i must have been writing off another problem. but thanks that fixed it.